# Oracle perform a count for each row on a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a doubt regarding a query in oracle SQL.
I have a groups table, that I can query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM groups g
WHERE g.owner = 123;
```

This would give something like:

| groupId | owner |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 123 |

I also have another table of administrators, that I can query as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM admins a
ORDER BY groupId;
```

This would get administrators as:

| adminId | userName | groupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | myadmin1 | 1 |
| 2 | myAdmin2 | 1 |
| 3 | myAdmin3 | 1 |
| 4 | myAdmin4 | 2 |
| 5 | myAdmin5 | 3 |
| 6 | myAdmin6 | 3 |

That basically means that a group can have multiple administrators. I would like to count the number of administrators for each group. A result such as:

| groupId | owner | adminCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 3 |
| 2 | 123 | 1 |
| 3 | 123 | 2 |
| 4 | 123 | 0 |

However, I cannot make a count of each administrator in the table and then make a join, as it is a table with a lot of rows.
I would like to perform the count query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM admins a
WHERE groupId = 1;
```

for each row of the groups query, such that I get the desired result without performing a count of each administrator in the table, just the ones that belong to the groups from a specific owner.

Does someone know how can I count it without counting all the rows in the administrators table?

Thanks

Comment: With up-to-date statistics Oracle will decide by itself which action should be performed first and what execution plan is cheaper. Loop is not a relational approach and without indexes it will consume much more resources than simple `join`, which is clear relational way to solve this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most readable variant is to use outer apply (or lateral(+)):

```
select *
from groups g
     outer apply (
       select count(*) as adminCount
       from admins a
       where a.groupId=g.groupId
     );
```

Or you can get the same results using subqueries (moreover, in fact Oracle optimizer can decide to transform outer-apply/lateral to this variant, since it has "lateral view decorrelation" transformation):

```
select g.groupId,g.owner, nvl(a.adminCount,0) as adminCount
from groups g
     left join (
         select x.groupId, count(*) as adminCount
         from admins x
         group by x.groupId
     ) a
     on a.groupId=g.groupId;
```

or even group-by with join:

```
select g.groupId,g.owner, count(a.groupId) as adminCount
from groups g
     left join admins a
          on g.groupId=a.groupId
group by g.groupId,g.owner
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/a-Q_abg8

Answer (score 2):

You could use analytic function COUNT() OVER() ...

```sql
Select  Distinct
        g.GROUP_ID,
        g.OWNER,
        Count(a.ADMIN_ID) OVER(Partition By g.GROUP_ID) "COUNT_ADMINS"
From    groups g
Left Join admins a ON(a.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID)
Where   g.OWNER = 123
Order By g.GROUP_ID
```

... this requires the Distinct keyword which could be performance costly with big datasets. I don't expect that user groups and admins are that big.
WIth your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    groups (GROUP_ID, OWNER) AS
        (
            Select 1, 123 From Dual Union ALL
            Select 2, 123 From Dual Union ALL
            Select 3, 123 From Dual Union ALL
            Select 4, 123 From Dual 
        ),
    admins (ADMIN_ID, ADMIN_USER_NAMAE, GROUP_ID) AS
        (
            Select 1, 'myadmin1', 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'myadmin2', 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'myadmin3', 1 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'myadmin4', 2 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'myadmin5', 3 From Dual Union All
            Select 6, 'myadmin6', 3 From Dual 
        )
```

... the result is

| GROUP_ID | OWNER | COUNT_ADMINS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 3 |
| 2 | 123 | 1 |
| 3 | 123 | 2 |
| 4 | 123 | 0 |